# Is it possible to load an initial value from an API into a formGroup or formControl without subscribing to an observable?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to load an initial value from an API into a formGroup or formControl without subscribing to an observable?

I want to load data from the API and keep the component reactiveX (using only the | async pipe).

For example:

```
public name: FormControl;
constructor(private api: apiService){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.name = new FormControl('');
  this.api.getName().subscribe(name => ...); // that line should be inside '' val without subscription

}
```

Comment: You could initialize your form in the `subscribe` method.

Comment: I know, but i don't wanna use subscribe.